# How to get started with Droid Explorer

Tags: droid-explorer

I've downloaded de.zip and unpacked it, although it came up with an error about something wrong with the header.
Now I have a folder with lots of things, but I have no clue how to get this app started. It doesn't look like a Windows program. I have no experience installing something on other platforms. Which platform is it meant for? Can someone please send me a link with installation info for that platform?

Keen to get started investigating the contents of a backup.ab file.
Many thanks!

Comment: For extracting Android backups use [Android Backup Extractor](https://github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor) (see section **Releases** and **Usage**). It is a Java command-line application. Hence you need to have Java Runtime (JRE) installed. For example this one: https://adoptopenjdk.net/installation.html?variant=openjdk11&jvmVariant=hotspot#x64_win-jre (The JRE from Oracle is also fine).

Comment: Did you see the tag wiki (click on that and see *learn more*) of the tag you used and the [frequently asked questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/droid-explorer?tab=Frequent) in that tag. Please read those and ask if it is not already covered there

Comment: @beeshyams You have to add that you have to click on the very small link "Learn more..." (IMHO a "design disaster" of StackExchange).  It took me ~10 years to recognize this link.

Comment: you click for releases see  https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJ4xu.png or https://github.com/camalot/droidexplorer/releases   I still can't get the program running though because https://github.com/camalot/droidexplorer/issues/77 (though seems to work for troynoks, though he is on win10 and me on win7, but maybe some other reason why it works for him and not me.. though anyhow the program has some issue and his answer while it works for him, is a workaround, and doesn't work for me)

Answer (score 2):

I liked this program for a long time. Once installed, but over time it stopped working. The reason is the SDK update !!!!!!!!!

DroidExplorer.0.9.0.4 does not work with the new SDK at all.

But you can set the Android SDK path manually in Windows Registry. On Windows 10 64bit you have to edit:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\DroidExplorer\InstallPath
```

Keep in mind that afterwards you should NEVER UPDATE SDK FROM THIS PROGRAM!

If you do as I use symbolic links in addition to critical files, then updating the main SDK will update the Droid Tools files.

But you can’t update sdk from the program anyway!

Comment: didn't work for me,  i'm on win7, I don't quite have the reg location of  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\DroidExplorer\InstallPath` 
  I have `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node`  and I have  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\DroidExplorer\InstallPath` which I used here https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLkka.png and just got the error of https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yOBz.png  ""  And if I make the path in the Wow6432Node location of the registry and set there then it still doesn't work  https://i.stack.imgur.com/bn1Cn.png