# droid explorer can't recognise sdk directory

Tags: droid-explorer

droid explorer can't recognise sdk directory

[image]

[image]

That is the SDK directory, it's what Android Studio shows under file..project structure. `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`

Comment: The Android SDK has changed a lot during the last years. I would assume DroidExplorer needs an update to detect it, therefore you should post this as an [issue on the Droid Explorer project](https://github.com/camalot/droidexplorer/issues).

Comment: @alecxs I don't mind supporting users that have problems using Droid Explorer - if it works at all. But if Droid Explorer does not recognize the Android SDK this requires changes on the source code of Droid Explorer itself which is out of scope of this site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get started with Droid Explorer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/224663/how-to-get-started-with-droid-explorer)

Comment: @Robert  thanks, though no it doesn't solve it, see my comment that I just posted on the answer posted there

Comment: As I wrote in my comment to alecxs I suspect that Droid Explorer requires an update to reflect the new layout of the Android SDK. May be the [issue](https://github.com/camalot/droidexplorer/issues/77) you have created changes something.